# How to put multiple assets in a data event for Android Development

Tags: java, android, wear-os

I am trying to make an app that sends files from my Android Watch to my Android Phone.

The problem I have is that if I record and save multiple files and send all of them at the same time, I do not get all the files back on the phone side. I only receive one file.

The code for sending the file is as follows. This code is implemented on the Watch side.:

```
public void sendData(View v){
    String fname = "_Activity.bin";
    int FileCounterCopy = FileCounter;
    if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
        for (int i = 0; i < FileCounterCopy ; i++){
            String FileName = String.valueOf(i) + fname;
            File dataFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), FileName);
            Log.i("Path", Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
            Log.i("file", dataFile.toString());

            Asset dataAsset = createAssetfromBin(dataFile);
            sensorData = PutDataMapRequest.create(SENSOR_DATA_PATH);
            sensorData.getDataMap().putAsset("File", dataAsset);

            PutDataRequest request = sensorData.asPutDataRequest();
            Wearable.DataApi.putDataItem(mGoogleApiClient, request).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DataApi.DataItemResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(DataApi.DataItemResult dataItemResult) {
                    Log.e("SENDING IMAGE WAS SUCCESSFUL: ", String.valueOf(dataItemResult.getStatus().isSuccess()));
                }
            });
            boolean deleted = dataFile.delete();
            Log.i("Deleted", String.valueOf(deleted));
            FileCounter--;
        }
        mTextView.setText(String.valueOf(FileCounter));
        Return();

    }
    else {
        Log.d("Not", "Connecteddddddddd");
    }

}
```

The code for receiving the files is as follows and is implemented on the phone side.

```
@Override
public void onDataChanged(DataEventBuffer dataEvents) {
    Counter++;
    final List<DataEvent> events = FreezableUtils.freezeIterable(dataEvents);
    dataEvents.close();
    Log.e("List Size: ", String.valueOf(events.size()));
    for (DataEvent event : events) {
        if (event.getType() == DataEvent.TYPE_CHANGED) {
            Log.v("Data is changed", "========================");
            String path = event.getDataItem().getUri().getPath();
            if (SENSOR_DATA_PATH.equals(path)) {
                DataMapItem dataMapItem = DataMapItem.fromDataItem(event.getDataItem());
                fileAsset = dataMapItem.getDataMap().getAsset("File");
                myRunnable = createRunnable();
                if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    new Thread(myRunnable).start();
            }
        }
    }
    status.setText("Received" + " File_"+ String.valueOf(Counter) );
}
```

Right before the for loop, I check the size of the event and it only shows a size of 1, no matter how many files I save.

I am stuck on how to implement this (tbh I used code from youtube video/online resources so I am not 100% sure on how some of the api works).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You're putting all of the files at the same path, with nothing to differentiate them - so each one you put in overwrites the previous ones. The Data API works much like a filesystem in this regard.

In your `sendData` method, you need code something like this:

```
sensorData = PutDataMapRequest.create(SENSOR_DATA_PATH + '/' + dataFile.toString());
```

And then in `onDataChanged`, either only check the path prefix...

```
if (path.startsWith(SENSOR_DATA_PATH)) {
```

...or, preferably, put the value of `SENSOR_DATA_PATH` in your manifest declaration as an `android:pathPrefix` element in the `intent-filter` of your data receiver. You can then remove the path check from your Java code completely. Docs for that are here: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/WearableListenerService

One other thing: it's good practice to clear stuff like these files out of the Data API when you're done using them, so that they're not taking up space there.